# Python throws module has no attibute error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a Python program that has the following import command:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and on line:

```
ax.imshow(worldmap, cmap=plt.cm.cmapname)
```

throws the following error:

```
<module>
    ax.imshow(worldmap, cmap=plt.cm.cmapname)
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cm' has no attribute 'cmapname'
```

The matplotlib library was installed with `pip install matplotlib`.

Strangely, this same program runs on another person's PC with no problem, and he has never seen this error before.  Would anyone know what is causing this error and how to fix it?

I'm running Python 3.9.1.  I'm wondering if we might be using different versions of matplotlib and whether this might be an issue.

Comment: It might occur because of different version of matplotlib. Please run `pip show matplotlib` on each computer.

Comment: There is no `cmapname` colormap - wherever you were copying that from was just using that as a placeholder...

Comment: Ali Irani had the right answer.  I was using Python 3.9.5 with matplotlib 3.4.2, and my friend was using Python 3.7.1 with matplotlib 3.0.3.  I installed what my friend was using, and his code worked.  By the way: I first tried installing matplotlib with Python 3.9.5, and it wouldn't install.  It seems that successive matplotlib versions are not upwardly compatible.  Really, you would expect that whatever worked with older versions should also work with newer versions, but this evidently is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Ali Irani had the right answer.  I was using Python 3.9.5 with matplotlib 3.4.2, and my friend was using Python 3.7.1 with matplotlib 3.0.3.  I installed what my friend was using, and his code worked.  By the way: I first tried installing matplotlib with Python 3.9.5, and it wouldn't install.  It seems that successive matplotlib versions are not upwardly compatible.  Really, you would expect that whatever worked with older versions should also work with newer versions, but this evidently is not the case.